# Empty string passed to getElementById() at query.unobtrusive-ajax.js:16

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC4 application and have started using jQuery actionlinks.
However when I run the following Razor code (and click the view ticket actionlink) I get a generic jQuery error (twice) saying that an empty string was passed to getElementById().
I have no idea where this error is happening since firefox merely links to the jQuery code.
This is my Razor code: (I know the js functions show and hideticket are empty but that is to simplify the code):

```
<script>
function ShowTicket(id) {
    $("#viewTicketButton" + id).hide();
    $("#hideTicketButton" + id).show();
    $("#viewTicket").show();
}

function HideTicket(id) {
    $("#viewTicketButton" + id).show();
    $("#hideTicketButton" + id).hide();
    $("#viewTicket").hide();
}
</script>

<h3>Your tickets</h3>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Title:</td>
        <td>Urgency:</td>
        <td>Status:</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (SupportTicketViewData t in Model.supportTicketViewDataList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@t.title</td>
            <td>@t.text</td>
            <td>@t.status</td>
            <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("View Ticket", "ViewTicket", new { id = t.id },
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "viewTicket",
                OnComplete = "ShowTicket(" + t.id +");"
            }, new { id = "viewTicket" + t.id })</td>
            <td><button  id="@Html.Raw("HideTicket" + t.id)" onclick="HideTicket(@t.id);">Hide Ticket</button></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<div id="viewTicket">
</div>
```

Also I get a result from the GET request just fine since it get's inserted into the div element however I get 2 errors when debugging in firefox.

Also when I click the viewTicketButton the button doesn't hide as it should.

Comment: have you got the JS Code as the error is likely in there?

Comment: @Trotts
Well the thing is that I still get the errors even with empty functions so I imagined that it cant be them. However I've updated the question with the JS code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you cannot simply do

```
OnComplete = "ShowTicket(" + t.id +");"
```

The argument must be a javascript function. If what you want to call is parameterless, you can do

```
OnComplete = "ShowTicket"
```

where show ticket is the function object, so this is fine.
In your case however, you've got to pass the ID to ShowTicket. Try the following:

```
OnComplete = "function() { ShowTicket(" + t.id +"); }"
```

Comment: Ahh that was indeed an error on my part. I do however still have the 2 getElementById() errors.
I don't know what's causing them and I don't know if they matter. But isn't there some way to see what line in my razor syntax that causes them?

Comment: Your best bet is to have a look at the HTML that is actually rendered, or even better use the browser's debugger (F12 in IE8+ and Chrome, CTRL+Shift+I in Opera 15 or Firefox) to see what gets passed to `getElementById()`, and take it from there to find out which part of your markup is responsible for it.

Answer (score 5):

Warnings '**Empty string passed to getElementById()**' occurs when sending form created via Ajax.BeginForm or Ajax.ActionLink with unobtrusive validation turned on.
In my case adding handlers to all events supported by Ajax.BeginForm fixed issue with warnings:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(“SomeAction”, null, new AjaxOptions() {
  OnBegin = “someFunction”,  
  OnComplete = “ShowTicket”,  
  OnFailure = “someFunction”,  
  OnSuccess = “someFunction”  
} 
....
```

I believe that this should fix your issue.
 More details about issue on my [blog post](http://afelin.tk/ajax-beginform-empty-string-passed-to-getelementbyid/).

Comment: I should have flagged it during review as it 1) doesn't provide an answer to specific question 2) is posted to thread with an accepted solution (green tick mark near answer) 3) thread wasn't active for the last 3 months. Keep that in mind next time ;) .

Comment: As Jordan Axe wrote, accepted answer fixed problem with handler execution but it didn't fix warnings from question title.

Comment: my bad, not really my cup of tea

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to add the slashes to compensate for the double quotes that you need in the id tag
eg:

Html.Raw("id=\"SomeIdString\"")